# How can I display a three latest posts from facebook on my website?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, posts

How can I display a three latest posts from facebook on my website? I wanna display latest posts from my fanpage on website. I searched internet and I haven't found a solution. Someone can help me to find solution?
I don't know how to do this. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You want to make use of the [graph api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api) that facebook provides.

For your post(s), you will want to see the following: [Get Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post)

These two references should get you on your way to displaying posts. The best thing to do first would be to use something like postman or your preferred HTTP client with graphql support to validate the requests before writing the requests in your own code base.